# Flex: How to get full screen, withsame vertical and horizontal bar, as it was just before full screen

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, actionscript-3

please check my code

// for Full Screen  `stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;`

// for the normal screen  `stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;`

But this code does not fulfill my requirement. I need Vertical Scroll Bar, even I go to the FullScreen, but I don't find any Scroll with this code.

Even I tried "window.open" of JavaScript with ExternalInterface, but I couldnot succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess Flex usually automatically hides scrol-bars as soon as they are not needed. In your case I would create a custom skin for Scroller or whatever component you are using. Here an example:

```
<fx:Metadata>
<![CDATA[ 
    /** 
     * @copy spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin#hostComponent
     */
    [HostComponent("spark.components.Scroller")]
]]>
</fx:Metadata> 

<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[    
    /**
     *  @private
     */
    override public function beginHighlightBitmapCapture() : Boolean
    {
        var needUpdate:Boolean = super.beginHighlightBitmapCapture();

        // Draw an opaque rect that fill our entire skin. Our background
        // is transparent, but we don't want focus/error skins to
        // poke through.  This is safe to do since we don't have any 
        // graphic elements as direct children.
        graphics.beginFill(0);
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);
        graphics.endFill();

        return needUpdate;
    }

    /**
     *  @private
     */
    override public function endHighlightBitmapCapture() : Boolean
    {
        var needUpdate:Boolean = super.endHighlightBitmapCapture();

        // Clear the rect we drew in beginBitmapCapture();
        graphics.clear();

        return needUpdate;
    }
]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:VScrollBar id="verticalScrollBar"/>

<s:HScrollBar id="horizontalScrollBar"/>
```

Comment: Hi Chrisdutz, your guess at this point is not appropriate, because at the normal view, it shows the Browser Vertical Bar, and page height is too big to hide the bar at the time of FullScreen.
and when I press Ctrl + F11, I get the vertical bars, with FullScreen.
So Actually I want the view just same as we press and see after Ctrl+F11.

Comment: Ok ... so you are not at all talking about a Scrollbar INSIDE your flex application, but the Scrollbar of the Browser?

Comment: Yes, and this browser scroll bar depends upon the contents in my page. If more contents then it will be shown, otherwise will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks chrisdutz for your reply, but finally I got that this is not possible if we want to get scrollBar in new window, without externelInterface. So I tried this JavaScript function:

function browserFullScreen(myUrl) 
{

```
    var url = myUrl;
    params  = 'width='+screen.width; 
    params += ', height='+screen.height;
    params += ', top=0, left=0';
    params += ', fullscreen=yes';
    params += ', scrollbars=yes';
    window.open (url, "_blank", params);
}
```

It really works. and because of so much google and other research, I found that Full Screen is possible with Flex code, but we can not get Browser Scroll Bars.

Thanks All.